# MYSQL - Left join a double relationship?

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT stores.ID, store_info.display_name, store_info.address,store_info.phone,
           IFNULL(
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT storeBrands.display_name ORDER BY storeBrands.name), 
           GROUP_CONCAT(chainBrands.display_name ORDER BY chainBrands.name)
          ) AS brands,
          IFNULL(
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT storeFilters.name ORDER BY storeFilters.name),
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT chainFilters.name ORDER BY chainFilters.name)
          ) AS filters
    FROM stores
      LEFT JOIN store_info ON stores.ID = store_info.storeID
      LEFT JOIN store_brands ON stores.ID = store_brands.store
      LEFT JOIN chain_brands ON stores.chainID = chain_brands.chain
      LEFT JOIN brands AS storeBrands ON store_brands.brand = storeBrands.ID
      LEFT JOIN brands AS chainBrands ON chain_brands.brand = chainBrands.ID
      LEFT JOIN store_filters ON  stores.ID = store_filters.store
      LEFT JOIN chain_filters ON stores.chainID = chain_filters.chain
      LEFT JOIN filters AS storeFilters ON store_filters.filter = storeFilters.ID
      LEFT JOIN filters AS chainFilters ON chain_filters.filter = chainFilters.ID
  WHERE stores.city = 1
  GROUP BY stores.ID
```

**I have updated this question because I have solved the initial problem myself, but there's still one more question:**

How can I improve on this?
I feel like I've made a *lot* of progress already. I have gone from doing a union with subqueries, to doing a single query with subqueries, to improving my joins up to the point where I don't need to do a subquery for each row anymore.

However, it still feels like it could be better. I'm very insecure about my joins.
Does anyone have tips of improvement here?

**The goal:**
I want this query to get results from a hierarchy. We have 'parents' (chains) that share the same brands and filters (and other things) as their own children(stores). The idea is for the 'child' to inherit the parent's settings as a fallback, but completely ignores it when it starts setting its own data.
So, basically, with one query, you want "either this data or that data", never both. One or the other. (Another reason why `UNION`won't really fit)

Comment: Why are you mixing JOINS and `FORM table1,table1` syntax. Make that a JOIN AS WELL

Comment: Is this not how it's supposed to be? I used this website as an example: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/  (see 'left join' section). They do it too, and it seemed logical to me. As far as I could understand, you do an initial query, and let `LEFT JOIN` add onto that query, allowing it to return NULL also. Right?

Comment: Yea but you have `FROM store_info, stores` one of those shoudl also be a JOIN

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok, done. I'm just confused as to why, exactly? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue myself, also making it way more efficient, removing most subqueries!

```
SELECT stores.ID, store_info.display_name, store_info.address,store_info.phone,
       IFNULL(
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT storeBrands.display_name ORDER BY storeBrands.name), 
         GROUP_CONCAT(chainBrands.display_name ORDER BY chainBrands.name)
        ) AS brands,
        IFNULL(
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT storeFilters.name ORDER BY storeFilters.name),
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT chainFilters.name ORDER BY chainFilters.name)
        ) AS filters
 FROM stores
    LEFT JOIN store_info ON stores.ID = store_info.storeID
    LEFT JOIN store_brands ON stores.ID = store_brands.store
    LEFT JOIN chain_brands ON stores.chainID = chain_brands.chain
    LEFT JOIN brands AS storeBrands ON store_brands.brand = storeBrands.ID
    LEFT JOIN brands AS chainBrands ON chain_brands.brand = chainBrands.ID
    LEFT JOIN store_filters ON  stores.ID = store_filters.store
    LEFT JOIN chain_filters ON stores.chainID = chain_filters.chain
    LEFT JOIN filters AS storeFilters ON store_filters.filter = storeFilters.ID
    LEFT JOIN filters AS chainFilters ON chain_filters.filter = chainFilters.ID
WHERE stores.city = $cityID
GROUP BY stores.ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the chain's only when the store has none, formulate a UNION.  One operand of the UNION joins the master data to the store data, while the other operand--instantiated only when the store has none--joins the master data to the chain data.  That's what one uses a UNION for: "I sometimes want these, and I sometimes want those."